# merging child-table date range with parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I asked a similar question in the past, and imagine there is already an answer for this, but I can't seem to figure out the wording to locate it.

I have a parent table with a date range and a child table that can have multiple date ranges within the date range of the parent table. I need to merge them into a row for each record in the series. An example should better explain what I'm trying:

Table 1 (Parent)

```
Date1    Date2    Person
1/1/16   7/1/16   A
```

and
Table 2 (Child)

```
Date1    Date2    Person
2/1/16   2/4/16   B
3/6/16   3/8/16   C
5/4/16   5/9/16   B
```

I want a merged table like so:

Merged Table

```
Date1    Date2    Person
1/1/16   2/1/16   A
2/1/16   2/4/16   B
2/4/16   3/6/16   A
3/6/16   3/8/16   C
3/8/16   5/4/16   A
5/4/16   5/9/16   B
5/9/16   7/1/16   A
```

There must be a somewhat easy way to do this? I'm fine with a complicated while loop, but am stumped on the logic for this too.

Comment: SQL2014. So it should be up to date with new functions/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, this is a modified version which considers multiple PK/FK

```
Declare @Table1 table (PK int,Date1 Date,Date2 Date, Person varchar(25))
Insert into @Table1 values 
(1,'1/1/16','7/1/16','A'),
(2,'2/1/16','8/1/16','A')


Declare @Table2 table (FK int,Date1 Date,Date2 Date, Person varchar(25))
Insert into @Table2 values 
(1,'2/1/16','2/4/16','B'),
(1,'3/6/16','3/8/16','C'),
(1,'5/4/16','5/9/16','B'),
(2,'3/1/16','3/4/16','B'),
(2,'3/6/16','3/8/16','C'),
(2,'5/4/16','5/9/16','B')


;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,Gap1 = Date2
          ,Gap2 = Lead(Date1,1,(Select max(Date2) from @Table1 Where FK=PK)) over (Partition By FK Order by Date1)
     From  @Table2 
)
Select PK,Date1,Date2=(Select min(Date1) from @Table2 Where FK=PK),Person From @Table1
Union All
Select FK,Date1,Date2,Person from cteBase
Union All
Select FK,Date1=Gap1,Date2=Gap2,Person=B.Person
 From  cteBase A
 Join  @Table1 B on FK=PK
 Where Gap1<>Gap2
Order by PK,Date1
```

Returns

```
PK  Date1       Date2       Person
1   2016-01-01  2016-02-01  A
1   2016-02-01  2016-02-04  B
1   2016-02-04  2016-03-06  A
1   2016-03-06  2016-03-08  C
1   2016-03-08  2016-05-04  A
1   2016-05-04  2016-05-09  B
1   2016-05-09  2016-07-01  A
2   2016-02-01  2016-03-01  A
2   2016-03-01  2016-03-04  B
2   2016-03-04  2016-03-06  A
2   2016-03-06  2016-03-08  C
2   2016-03-08  2016-05-04  A
2   2016-05-04  2016-05-09  B
2   2016-05-09  2016-08-01  A
```

Comment: @Julian  Once again, Happy to Help,  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Declare @Table1 table (Date1 Date,Date2 Date, Person varchar(25))
Insert into @Table1 values 
('1/1/16','7/1/16','A')

Declare @Table2 table (Date1 Date,Date2 Date, Person varchar(25))
Insert into @Table2 values 
('2/1/16','2/4/16','B'),
('3/6/16','3/8/16','C'),
('5/4/16','5/9/16','B')

;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,Gap1 = Date2
          ,Gap2 = Lead(Date1,1,(Select max(Date2) from @Table1)) over (Order by Date1)
     From  @Table2 
)
Select Date1,Date2=(Select min(Date1) from @Table2),Person From @Table1
Union All
Select Date1,Date2,Person from cteBase
Union All
Select Date1=Gap1,Date2=Gap2,Person=B.Person
 From  cteBase A
 Join  @Table1 B on 1=1 
Order by Date1
```

Returns

```
Date1       Date2       Person
2016-01-01  2016-02-01  A
2016-02-01  2016-02-04  B
2016-02-04  2016-03-06  A
2016-03-06  2016-03-08  C
2016-03-08  2016-05-04  A
2016-05-04  2016-05-09  B
2016-05-09  2016-07-01  A
```

Comment: I would have no way to build that myself, but it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!!! I love this community! I can work out the rest myself with a loop, but is there a better, more efficient way to do this same process with multiple rows in table1 that are joined via PK/FK to table2? So if Table1 had say two rows with unique IDs and then Table2 had 5 with 3 being the child of one row and 2 with the other, only merging those with matching PK/FK? Does that make sense?

Comment: Happy to help,  No need for a loop.  If you post a richer (or expanded) sample data-set, I can modify my answer